# Purpose of equivalent new Guid() and Guid.Empty

Tags: c#, guid

`new Guid()` and `Guid.Empty` produces the same results (all-0 guid (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).

```
var guid = new Guid();
Console.WriteLine(guid);//00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
var emptyGuid = Guid.Empty;
Console.WriteLine(emptyGuid);//00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Is this a two different manners to do the same thing ? readabilty reasons ? or i'm missing something ?

Comment: what is `empty` here? it is `emptyGuid ` na?

Comment: I'll say readability and simmetry with `string` (but note that you can't `new string()`) and other structures/classes that have an `Empty` static value.

Comment: Same as `Vector3.Zero` - stating clear intent. I've seen too many people assume that `new Guid()` returns an initialized, random GUID in the past.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Guid` is a `struct`. All structs have an *implicit default constructor* which initializes all members to their default value. In `Guid`, you see that as setting all it's composite members to `0`.

[`Guid.Empty` simply caches the default value](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,13baca63417ef924,references) via the invocation of the default constructor:

```
public struct Guid : IFormattable, IComparable, IComparable<Guid>, IEquatable<Guid>
{
    public static readonly Guid Empty = new Guid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of answering the question, through a concrete example :

C# lets you create generic types (**templates**) that take **parameter types**.

For example :

```
public class MyTemplate<T>
```

You can define all sorts of **constraints** on T : *"Not null"*, *"has a constructor"*, *"is a class"*, etc.

Like this:

```
public class MyTemplate<T> where T: notnull, new() // etc.
```

Extra constraint: You might want to make T *not nullable* and still return the *default* value, which might not be "null"!

```
public class MyTemplate<T> where T: notnull, new() {
    public MyTemplate() {
        var t = new T(); // If T is a Guid, then this returns Guid.Empty.
        //var t = default; // Even if T is a Guid, 
                           // C# will still panic here because 
                           // it's not sure if the "default" of T 
                           // (which you know to be Guid.Empty)
                           // is nullable or not -- despite you 
                           // having defined T as notnull!
    }
}
```

In conclusion :

You can see for yourself that depending on the context, the **same value** (Guid.Empty) can spawn from a **different concept** : In one case it's the result of a parameter-less constructor, in the other case it's a default value.

Since C# cannot predict what you want to do (if you go deep enough into abstraction, then you might want one scenario, or the other, or both!) it implements all the concepts **separately** , even if they give the same result. So you end up with both `new Guid()` and `Guid.Empty` , to make use case (every abstraction) happy.